# How do I get the arguments for any python method?

Tags: python, decorator, introspection

Normally I would use inspect.getargspec, however how do I get the arguments of a method that has been bound?

Eg, how do I get the argument names for the method 'foo' as follows:

```
class Foo(object):

    @memoized
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

Note that Foo().foo is a memoized object, http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

This means that it is really a functools.partial instance.

How do I get the original function or alternatively, obtain the arguments somehow?

If I can't, does this indicate a design flaw of the PythonDecoratorLibrary?

Comment: I have worked around this by effectively writing my own Memoize replacement that allows me to get the original function, however this question still stands.

Comment: eryksun: I did add a _wrapped attribute to the partial, although it seems weird because it already has a .func (which seems to be a curried function?), but the 'return self.func instead of the partial if obj is None' is very intruging. Could you put that in as an 'answer', I may accept it.  I'm using 2.7.x, however that mention of python3's lru_cache looks like something I should be aware of, could you provide a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a _wrapped attribute to the partial, which may be what you did already:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    """Support instance methods."""
    f = functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
    f._wrapped = self.func
    return f
```

Or you could return self.func instead of the partial if obj is None (i.e. if it's accessed from the class instead of an instance):

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    """Support instance methods."""
    if obj is None:
        return self.func
    else:
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

The partial's `func` attribute is the memoized object's `__call__` method. If you call it from a Foo instance, then the first argument is set to the instance obj by the partial (see this in Foo().foo.args). Then in `memoized.__call__`, self.func(*args) works like a poor man's bound method.

For the lru_cache, Raymond Hettinger has Python 2 compatible implementations available as [ActiveState Code Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/?in=user-178123). There's also a version for least frequently used, in addition to least recently used.

Comment: That second code example there looks especially elegant, thanks! (The lru_cache is applicable, as well - pity I can't accept this twice...)